# Java executes arithmetic Expression wrong?

Tags: java

I don`t understand how Java is progressing this arithmetic expression

```
int x = 1;
int y = 1;
x += y += x += y;
System.out.println("x=" + x + " y=" + y);
```

With Java I get x = 4 and y = 3. But in C, Perl, Php I get x=5 and y = 3
On the paper I also get x = 5 and y = 3

Comment: Don't assume that all languages treat statements with side effects in the same way. Java isn't getting it "wrong" - it's just defined differently to other languages. You should avoid this sort of code anyway.

Comment: That's because in Java, the behavior of such horrible code is well-defined, whereas in C at least, it's not. Read the Java Language Spec, or decide that it's useless, because anyone writing code like this should be fired anyway.

Comment: I see x = 4 and y = 3. For me that's perfect. Don't know how perl, php and C manage this, but for me looks fine.

Comment: IIRC this is actually undefined behavior in C so what it does in C is totally meaningless.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the nasty part, obviously:

```
x += y += x += y;
```

This is executed as:

```
int originalX = x; // Used later
x = x + y; // Right-most x += y
y = y + x; // Result of "x += y" is the value stored in x
x = originalX + y; // Result of "y += x" is the value stored in y
```

So:

```
                     x      y
(Start)              1      1
x = x + y            2      1
y = y + x            2      3
x = originalX + y    4      3
```

The important part is the use of `originalX` here. The compound assignment is treated as:

```
x = x + y
```

and the first operand of `+` is evaluated *before* the second operand... which is why it takes the *original* value of `x`, not the "latest" one.

From [JLS section 15.16.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2):

> If the left-hand operand expression is not an array access expression, then:
>
> - First, the left-hand operand is evaluated to produce a variable. If this evaluation completes abruptly, then the assignment expression completes abruptly for the same reason; the right-hand operand is not evaluated and no assignment occurs.
> - Otherwise, the value of the left-hand operand is saved and then the right-hand operand is evaluated. If this evaluation completes abruptly, then the assignment expression completes abruptly for the same reason and no assignment occurs.

When in doubt, consult the language specification - and never assume that just because two languages behave differently, one of them is "wrong". So long as the actual behaviour matches the specified behaviour for each language, all is well - but it does mean you need to understand the behaviour of each language you work with, of course.

That said, you should clearly avoid horrible code like this in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

it starts from right to left

```
1. x += y gives x = 2, y = 1
2. y += ( x +=y ) gives x = 2, y = 3
3. x += ( y += x += y ) gives x = 4, y = 3
```

so, it's all consistent

Comment: Your step 2 results are wrong - when/how did `x` go back to being 1? It should show x = 2, y = 3. (That's what you'd get if the whole statement was just `y += x += y;`) At that point you need to explain why the final value is 4... which takes a bit more work.

Comment: But you haven't explained why `x += ...` gives an answer of 4, not 5. Naively, one might think that if the value of `x` is 2, and the value of `y` is 3, then `x += y` will give x = 5. The important part is that `x` is evaluated *before any of the rest happens* and that's the value which is added to in the last step.

Comment: I put it short, you put it long. what's the problem?

Comment: You didn't "put it" at all, in my view. A language could be specified such that the compound assignment operator evaluates the right hand side first, *then* evaluates the variable and adds the relevant amount - everything in your answer would still apply, but it would give a different result.

Comment: I answered the question as briefly as it was asked. Of course you can go deeply in details and start with primitive types and variable definitions if you like. It's just another level. Someone is looking for short answers, others for longer ones. If both of them are correct it's fine.

Comment: But it's *not* correct because it doesn't explain why the answer is 4. As I said, if your answer can be applied to two languages which can give different results, then it doesn't explain either result. When an answer can be brief and still actually answer the question, that's great - but when brevity means not giving enough information, it makes the answer worthless IMO.